# How to get the parent item index inside child repeater?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have **nested repeaters** like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestoes" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <ol class="orderedList">
                    </HeaderTemplate>

                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionName")%>

                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptAlternativas" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("Questionario") %>' runat="server">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ul style="list-style-type: none">
                                </HeaderTemplate>

                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <li>
                                        <input id="rb" type="radio" name='ITEM_INDEX_HERE' value='<%#Container.DataItem("AlternativeID")%>' /><%#Container.DataItem("AlternativeName")%>
                                    </li>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </ul>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </ol>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to print the **parent item index** inside the child repeater (rptAlternativas) in VB right in `ITEM_INDEX_HERE` marker. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone can give you a better answer than this, but I would consider adding a property to your "Quentionario" sub elements.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAlternativas" 
   DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("Questionario") %>' 
   runat="server">
```

Can you add a question id to each of these objects?  You're already binding to their `AlternativeId` in your radio button, adding a question id to these objects would let you do simply:

```
  <input id="rb" type="radio" name='<%#Container.DataItem("QuestionId")%>' value='<%#Container.DataItem("AlternativeID")%>' />
```

Even if these objects are auto-generated from an ORM, you should be able to add the property in via a partial class, and then just set the appropriate values in a simple loop.

Comment: That's what I did in the first time, but the questions are chosen randomly, and I need to be able to retrieve every answer from the questions. I can't do that for I don't know the exact QuestionIDs to use Request.Form("MY_QUESTION_ID")

Comment: The questions may be chosen at random, but is there really no "key" value associated with them?